# $f\colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is $C^2$ and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. If $f'(x) \to b$ as $x \to \infty$, show that $b = 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f\colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ has continuous first and second derivatives and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. If $f'(x) \to b$ as $x \to \infty$, show that $b = 0$.

Shall I start by assuming $b$ is not $0$? Or use limit definition of derivative?

Comment: Suppose $b\neq 0$, by contradiction (without loss of generality, $b>0$). Then, there exists $A > 0$ such that $f^\prime(x) > \frac{b}{2}$ for $x \geq A$ (why?). Consider now $f(x) - f(A) = \int_A^x f^\prime \geq \dots$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $b\geq 0$ (the case $b\leq 0$ is similar). Then there exists $x_0$ such that, for all $x>x_0$, we have $f'(x)\geq b/2$. Then, for any $x>x_0$, we get from the Mean Value Theorem that 
$$
f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c)\,(x+1-x)\geq \frac b2\,(x+1-x)=\frac b2.
$$
Now take the limit as $x\to\infty$, and we get $0\geq b/2\geq0$, so $b=0$.

Comment: I must have missed something (in the question, answer, or both). Why is the assumption on $f^{\prime\prime}$ needed (our method seems to only require differentiability)? (Also, in your application of the MVT, the $x-x_0$ part in the middle should be $(x+1)-x$)

Comment: I don't think the assumption on $f''$ is needed.